# TinyMCE : Can't get focus with tabindex

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm facing some issue setting focus on the editor when navigating with TAB.

If my div doesn't have tabindex to set, and just click into it, the code below is working well, I can see the two console.log, init and focus, and the toolbar appears properly :

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on("init", function() {
        console.log('init');
        editor.focus();
    });
    editor.on("focus", function() {
        console.log('focus');
    });
}
```

But when I set a tabindex on the div, and TAB into it, I can only see the "init" one. The cursor is in place receiving text but there's no toolbar.
I have to TAB out and then TAB in again, to see this time the "focus" one and the toolbar.

Does anyone have some help ?

PS: The tab_focus plugin don't fit my needs because there can be several editors in the page and they aren't init on page load but on click, and now i'm trying to figure out how I can turn that click action onto a focus by TAB one.

Comment: What tabIndex value did you set?

Comment: I have set a tabindex=0 because I want the editor to keep the TAB flow of the form

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issues this way :

```
editor.on("init", function() {
    $(focusElement).blur();
    $(focusElement).focus();
});
```

Because the original

```
editor.on("init", function() {
    editor.focus();
});
```

don't work with TAB naigation I had to do this trick to fake the thing that I had to TAB out and then TAB in again to trigger the focus event.